# Modify inputText value onBlur

Tags: jsf

I am JSF with PrimeFaces 5.1 in my project need onBlur remove specify character i.e in text `01,02,03,,` or `01,02,03` or `01,02,03,,,,` this text box value I need `01,02,03` using javascript is possible or anyother way

Comment: `'01,02,03,,,,'.replace(new RegExp(/,{1,}$/g),'')`

Answer (score 1):

use this trimRight method: https://www.sitepoint.com/trimming-strings-in-javascript/

```js
String.prototype.trimRight = function(charlist) {
  if (charlist === undefined)
    charlist = "\s";

  return this.replace(new RegExp("[" + charlist + "]+$"), "");
};

console.log("01,02,03,,,".trimRight(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "01,02,03,,,,";
//Keep checking if the trailing character is ','
while(input && input.charAt(input.length-1) == ","){
  //if true trim the last character and continue
  input = input.substring(0,input.length-1);
}
console.log(input);
```

Comment: Whilst this code may solve the OP's problem your answer can be greatly improved by explaining how and why that is the case. That will be more valuable for increasing the understanding of all future readers compared to a code only answer with no explanation.

Comment: @lmo , kaylum I thought it was very simple hence didn't add any explanation. Anyway, now I have added necessary comments